# how to make a script for clicking on a button on a web page?

Tags: javascript, html, windows, web

I like to time track my day with this page https://www.timeanddate.com/stopwatch/

After clicking on the "start" button if you then "pause" you will see a "Export results as text" button.

I would like to make a windows script that every X amount of hours it:

1. goes to my firefox browser
2. clicks on the timer tab (is a fixed tab
   that's always in the same location)
3. clicks on "pause"
4. clicks on "Export results as text" and then save the file
5. clicks on "start"

How do I do that?

Comment: you could try using `puppeteer`

Comment: I was about to give the same suggestion as @KrzysztofKrzeszewski

Comment: great! It looks like the thing i am looking for. Thks